# ASP.NET MVC 3 - How do I allow to enter in html textarea

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, editor

I want to use granular data validation. `[AllowHtml]` attribute not working with `FormCollection`. There are any alternative than to use `ValidateInput(false)`?

in metadata:

```
[AllowHtml]
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
[Display(Name = "Content")]
public string Content { get; set; }

in edit action:

[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection formCollection)
{
    var obj = service.Get(id);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        UpdateModel(obj, formCollection);
        service.Update(obj);

        return OnEdited(obj);
    }

    return View(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use AllowHtml with FormCollection. You could use the `[ValidateInput]` attribute but obviously this disabled validation for all values:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Edit(FormCollection collection, int id)
{
    var myEntity = _myRepo.Get(id);
    TryUpdateModel(objective);
    return DoSave(objective);
}
```

This being said I would use the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(MyEntity entity)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _myRepo.Save(entity);
        return RedirectToAction("Success");
    }
    return View(entity);
}
```

A simplified reason why it does not work when binding FormCollection is because there's nothing that associates the fact that you have AllowHtml defined on some property of some class with the currently executing request.

Comment: But if I use the following:

`[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(MyEntity entity)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _myRepo.Save(entity);
        return RedirectToAction("Success");
    }
    return View(entity);
}`

i get an error **A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client**.

Comment: I use `public ActionResult Edit(FormCollection collection, int id)` because Edit action is declared in the base class.

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Edit(T obj)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (TryUpdateModel(obj))
        {
            T old = service.Get(obj.ID);
            UpdateModel(old);
            service.Update(old); // EntityModelObject.SaveChanges();

            return OnEdited(obj);
        }
    }

    return View(obj);
}
```